# Reset the open file window size in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, window

How can I reset the open file window in Google Chrome back to it's default size?

My wife resized it when uploading photo's to a website and I would like to reset it

I have deleted the BagMRU & Bags registry keys, but they do not appear to affect Chrome

I have also deleted my user profile and started Chrome from scratch but that does not make any difference either

Thank you

Comment: If you re-size the window and click the red x button instead of opening a file it should save it's state.

Comment: Too late for that I'm afraid :(

Comment: @Ben, Justin was actually talking about the close-button of Chrome, which wouldn’t affect the File Dialog anyway.

Comment: Where were the Bag keys you deleted (which key)?

Comment: I followed this http://superuser.com/questions/3347/how-to-make-explorer-in-vista-remember-a-folders-view

Comment: @Synetech Actually, I was talking about the close button on the file dialog itself. In my testing, it seemed to retain the settings when that button was pressed after resizing.

Comment: Ah, okay. You mean the “red” close button because of Vista/7’s Aero theme right? I thought you were talking about Chrome’s “red” button because of Chrome’s theme. Anyway, yes, it does remember, but only until you restart the program.

Answer (score 4):

No, Chrome isn’t a normal window, so ShellBags has no effect on it. Instead, Chrome handles its own window-positioning (well, normally, when it works; sometimes it gets stuck or reset/forgets).

First, close all Chrome windows (and make sure that there are no `CHROME.EXE` instances running in Task Manager). Open your Chrome profile (the `User Data` folder) and look for the `Local State` file. Open it in a text-editor and look for the `window_placement` section inside the `browser` section and delete that—this is a structured file, so make sure to get the quotes and braces correctly. (There are other `window_placement` sections for other things like the Options dialog, Task Manager, etc.) Finally, save and open Chrome; it should open at a “default” location, but should remember where you set it when you subsequently close it.

Comment: I have closed Chrome and looked in the Local State file, but there is no mention of window_placement at all

Comment: That’s strange. Is there a line as follows? `"browser": {` Try searching for `work_area_bottom` (though there could be several of these).

Comment: All I have in the browser section is: `{
   "browser": {
      "hung_plugin_detect_freq": 2000,
      "last_known_google_url": "http://www.google.co.uk/",
      "last_prompted_google_url": "http://www.google.co.uk/",
      "last_redirect_origin": "",
      "plugin_message_response_timeout": 30000
   },`

Comment: I found them under `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` removing them resets the Chrome window size and location, however I want to reset the open file dialogue window, ie Ctrl+O, also the same window when you browse for a file you wish to attach to an email in Gmail

Comment: I've also uninstalled Chrome, deleted the Chrome folder under AppData\Local\Google, reinstalled, but still the open file window is still not back to it's default setting

Comment: That’s still strange; I **don’t** have them in `Preferences`. Ah okay. The file-dialog *is* a Windows window and is not controlled by Chrome. Worse, those dialogs are not stored in ShellBags, so I’m not sure where/how their position can be controlled, though I’ll give it some thought and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: From what I can tell (and test), the FileDialog does not have any specific sizing/positioning control and Windows does not save or keep track of said attributes. The size/position is temporarily saved separately for each application when you change it, but when you then quit the program and run it again, it is reset to the default (ie, they are only saved per-app, per-session not globally or permanently). The only way to save/control the size/position is to manually save/restore it and use use a special File Dialog that incorporates the function (not the Common Control), which Chrome does not.

Comment: I find it strange that you are experiencing something other than this behavior. Can you add a screenshot to your question to clarify the situation?

Comment: Here is Chrome on my work laptop (default) https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/cFE5V16sxMDiuSV-2qg4mpYZ6RqNmTIZXJFuHJtYmlI?feat=directlink here is my home PC https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/kjC1hcFROrpAce2b6Y8FmpYZ6RqNmTIZXJFuHJtYmlI?feat=directlink where is the size of this window stored?

Comment: Like I said, it’s not. You can change it all you like and it will remember it, but only until you quit. When you exit the program (completely, again make sure that there is no `CHROME.EXE` left in the Task Manager), and then run the program again, it *should* be reset to the defaults. You can test it yourself with Notepad or other app.

Comment: Wait, are other File Dialogs like that too (eg Notepad->Open…) or is it **only** in Chrome?

Comment: Only Chrome, everything else is fine

Comment: Hmm, curiouser and curiouser… What versions of Chrome are they? I see you’re using Vista/7; when you deleted the keys, did you get the ones in `…Classes\Local Settings…`? Vista/7 store the window position/sizes in [a different location](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813711) than XP (although apparently a fresh install erroneously creates the old XP keys).

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on 44.0.2403.157 m

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you close the Chrome application (since it still running and writing- and overwriting your changes- to the "Local State" file even though you can't see the maximized Chrome window).

Next, find the file c:\Users{UserNameHere}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State
and delete (or rename) the whole the file and restart Chrome.

All your previously opened tabs will be present and the default page position/size will be restored.

Comment: Generic alternative to path provided: %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State

Answer (score 2):

To permanently set the Chrome window size and position add the following switches to the shortcut that opens Chrome. You can adjust the path and numbers to suit your own situation.

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --window-position=200,50 --window-size=1400,900

To apply these switches, right click the Chrome shortcut and choose "properties". Add the switches to the target textbox. Start each switch with a space followed by -- and then the a switch as shown above. A second switch can be added by leaving a space and then writing the next one. The switches used here are
--window-position=200,50
--window-size=1400,900

Don't leave any spaces within the switch.
Always start a switch with a space and then --
Place the switches outside the path quotes ("").

Comment: Sorry I can't vote twice : )

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure this out either, but somewhere I had messed up a setting. Performing a system restore seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Default window opening size is a widows thing.  Just need to set the size you would like it to open, hold down Ctl and close the window, next time you open it, it will be that size and position.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood the question, its about `Open File` Dialog Box resizing issue, and I posted answer about resetting weird browser window size on open. :Facepalm:

I had similar issue where my browser opens tiny in top left corner randomly one day. After reading all the answers here, I simply used <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> and closed the browser. Next time, it opens maximized and fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

What worked super simple for me.  I just right clicked on the close red X and then hit restore.  And that worked.