# How can I drag the browser window under Chrome OS back on-screen?

Tags: google-chrome-os

I am running Chrome OS in a virtual machine. For some reason, the browser has gone to the bottom right corner and there is no way I can drag it back. Because of this problem, the whole user account becomes unusable. I tried to delete the useraccount, but I cannot seem to do it as it's the default account.

I know everything works if I use a different account, but it's better to have it fixed. Any idea?

Comment: What OS are you running Chrome in (i.e. The VM OS)? If it is Windows, refer to [this previous SU answer](http://superuser.com/a/288127/19999).

Comment: Fideli, this question is about [Chrome OS](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os).

Comment: yes, it's Chrome OS. to be more specific, it's Chromium, but it's Chrome OS anyway

Comment: Can you put a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the keyboard:

1. Select the window that you want to move back to the main screen area via the task bar or <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Alt+Space</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>M</kbd>, then an arrow key (eg <kbd>Down</kbd>)
4. Move the mouse/cursor to snap the window onto the screen and move it as desired

Comment: This works for **Windows**. Do you know if it results in the same behavior under **Chrome OS**?

Comment: I don’t know about the window context-menu or sizing controls, but at least the `Alt+Tab` part to select the window [should work](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183101). Maybe `Ctrl+Alt+?` can give more information.