# How can I restore the original default window size for Google Chrome in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

Per the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/288046/reset-the-open-file-window-size-in-google-chrome), I closed Chrome from the taskbar, ensured there were no chrome.exe entries in Task Manager, opened `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` in Notepad++, removed the `,"window_placement":{...}` portion, saved, and reopened Chrome. There was no change in the defaults. I also tried modifying the settings instead of removing them altogether, but they just changed back when I opened Chrome again. I suspect something's changed in the past six years -- the settings have to be stored *somewhere*.

(I don't even know how it got changed to a tiny window way off-screen to the top-right in the first place. It was like that when I opened it, and I hadn't restarted since before the last time I opened Chrome the night before.)

Comment: You should be able to change the size of the window with the standard keyboard shortcuts

Comment: `chrome --window-position=x,y --window-size=w,h`

Comment: My goal is not just to resize the window, but to make it so that in the future, a new window will open with the original default size.